# Bootstrap form submission not able to use $_POST data

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, post

My code in not entering any data from the boostrap form into MySQL table, if I hard code the values instead of using $login and $score, the data shows up in my table.

Here's my form (index.php)

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">NA</span>

            <input type="text" id = "login" name = "login" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">-</span>
            <input type="int" id = "score" name = "score" class="form-control" placeholder="Score: (0-10)"/>


            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <a class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="submit" href = "/insert.php">Rate!</a>
       </span>

</form>
```

and my php (insert.php)

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "data";

$login=$_POST['login'];
$score=$_POST['score'];


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

print("name data: $login");
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (name, score)
VALUES ('$login', '$score')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

both name and score are empty in each addition of my data.

edit: fixed, thank you

```
 <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Rate</button>
```

Comment: Does "echo $_POST['login'];" print anything at all if you place it at the top of your file? Just wondering: could it be that there's an error on the connection and you hit die()?

Comment: it prints "New record created successfully" That's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use  button for submit instead of using a href link

try this

```
 <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Rate!</button>
```

Comment: Oh my god it worked, thank you so much! After hours of pulling my hair out to figure out why this stupid thing wasn't working. So simple too.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use

```
 <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" value ="Rate">
```